# Calculate the Rates based on the Hour value SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In our application we follow the below pattern to save the hours spent by an employee.

- for 30 minutes = 0.30
- for 1 hour     = 1

So if an employee works 1 hour 30 minutes, then the hours value would be `1.30.`

We also calculate the wages for each employee using below formula.

```
wages = rate * hours
```

If an employee has an hourly rate of `50$`, his wages for 1 hour 30 minutes would be `75$`. But as per our data structure we got

```
wages = 50 * 1.30 = 65
```

How can I get the correct wages?

(Note: we were not permitted to change the data structure in the table. i.e to make the 1 hour 30 minutes as 1.50)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Convert the minutes to hour value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example how to convert your number to hours, that you can multiply on th wage.

```
declare @t decimal(5,2)=1.3

/* converting to hours */
select cast(@t as int)+@t%1*100/60
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    cast(substring('1.30',charindex('.','1.30')+1,len('1.30')) as float)/60
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @col FLOAT
SET @col = 1.30

DECLARE @hours FLOAT
SET @hours = (SELECT FLOOR(@col) + (@col - FLOOR(@col))/0.6)
```

THEN `wages = rate * @hours`

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Hours DECIMAL(18,2)
DECLARE @Rate MONEY
SET @Rate = 50
SET  @Hours = 1.3
SELECT (CAST(@Hours AS INT) + (@Hours - CAST(@Hours AS INT))/.6)*@Rate
```